# Function isn't valid

Tags: vba

What am I doing Wrong?

[image]

```
Function group(item As String) As String

If item = "789-JBRT-JK" Then
    group = "Software"
End If

End Function
```

Comment: Excel doesn't like "group" as a UDF name - if to change it to (eg) "groupname" it will work

Comment: WOW! it worked. I spent some time on that. Thanks dude!